# Error while uploading images to Imgur with api in Android

Tags: java, android, imgur, networkonmainthread

I am working with the Imgur API for uploading images. The image is clicked using a camera and stored as a bitmap which is further converted into Base-64 String.

I'm then passing the Base-64 string to a function which should upload the image to Imgur. But the code returns the Error:
`android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Image capture and convert to Base-64:

```java
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                            //Bitmap part
                            Intent data = result.getData();
                            Bitmap captureImage=(Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                            //Base-64 part 
                            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            captureImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
                            byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
                            String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

                            upload(encoded);
                            //profilePic.setImageBitmap(captureImage);
                        }
                    }
                });
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Camera Capture
                Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                someActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
            }
        });
```

Code to upload:

```java
public void upload(String encoded){
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .build();
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("text/plain");
        RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("image",encoded)
                .build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://api.imgur.com/3/image")
                .method("POST", body)
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Client-ID {{MY_ID}}")
                .build();
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            Log.wtf("RESPONSE",""+response);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I'm using Android Studio and running the app on an AVD (API-30) if that matters.

Comment: Execute `upload()` function in a background thread. Or, use something like [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) to create your API requests. [related docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException)

Comment: @rupinderjeet I'm sorry but what's a background thread?

Comment: Main thread is responsible for drawing your UI (activities, fragments, views). Android doesn't allow you to execute network requests on this thread because these requests will block Main thread. So, instead, we use a background thread that can execute CPU or I/O tasks without effecting app's UI and animations. [Read this blog post](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html) to know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your upload() function on background thread:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        //Bitmap part
                        Intent data = result.getData();
                        Bitmap captureImage=(Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                        //Base-64 part 
                        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        captureImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
                        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
                        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

new Thread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    upload(encoded);  //background stuff
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // do onPostExecute stuff
        }
    });
}
}).start();                        
                        //profilePic.setImageBitmap(captureImage);
                    }
                }
            })
```

Note:The above solution is not the best way of doing async task.The best option is Rxjava/RxAndroid for asynchronous task.